# logging bash scripts with verbose and xtrace (set -vx) and customizing PS4

Tags: bash, debugging, shell

I am trying to configure PS4 for better xtrace output when I also have verbose set for verbose mode. Several of the things I would like to do spawn subshells but I want to see any -x or -v output for those operations because they would print for every line.

I also wanted to get rid of the nesting/indirection depth level indicator (+) because I want the trace output to be aligned.

My initial idea was:

```
BACKSPACES=$'\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b'
PS4='+`printf "%s[\t] %-16.16s:%03d (%-16.16s) $ " ${BACKSPACES:0:$BASH_SUBSHELL} $(basename $BASH_SOURCE) $LINENO ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}}`'
```

The first problem I ran into was that $BASH_SUBSHELL doesn't always seem to be the same as the number of +'s that would print. Looking into $SHLVL didn't help either.

```
echo $X
+ 0 2 $ echo x <-- toplevel prints one + and $BASH_SUBSHELL is 0, as expected
x

( echo subshell )
+ 1 2 $ echo subshell <-- $BASH_SUBSHELL increments to 1 as expected, but why only one + instead of two ++?

source ./test2.sh
+ 0 2 $ source ./test2.sh
echo $X$X$X$X
++ 0 2 $ echo xxxx <-- ??? is $BASH_SUBSHELL relative to the current file or something but the + indicators are not???
xxxx
subshell
```

I think I have gotten around this by forgetting about using $BASH_SUBSHELL and instead making the first character in PS4 an unprintable one but I'd still like to know why $BASH_SUBSHELL isn't what I expect.

To work around the issue with subshells being created within PS4, I looked an equivalent of PS1's PROMPT_COMMAND but didn't find anything except some indications on how to implement it myself.

The best way I thought I found was to trap the DEBUG signal.

```
trap 'debugfun $BASH_SOURCE' DEBUG
```

Of course, the -vx options also apply to calls to debugfun. My solution to suppress that output was to wrap the function's steps in set +vx and set -vx.

```
debugfun() {
  set +vx
  VAR=`basename $1 .sh`
  set -vx
}
```

Now... I had to deal with the matter of every call printing:

```
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE <-- from -v
++ debugfun ./test.sh <-- from -x
++ set +vx <-- from -x
```

I'm not sure why -v doesn't cause a print on the "set +vx" line either. I thought -T option might do that but it didn't.

Anyway, I thought the output was always going to consistent so all I had to do was erase those 3 lines from within debugfun. My ugly solution was to add this line after the "set +vx":

```
printf "\b\r\033[K\b\r\033[K\b\r\033[K" # clear previous 3 lines
```

It worked!

... Except when I pipe more than once.

I'll remove the printf line to show why:

```
echo $X$X | sed 's/x/y/' # pipe once... debugfun is called every time before each pipe component
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE
++ debugfun ./test.sh
++ set +vx
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE
++ debugfun ./test.sh
++ set +vx
+ echo xx
+ sed s/x/y/

echo $X$X$X | sed 's/x/y/' | sed 's/y/x/' # pipe twice 
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE
++ debugfun ./test.sh
++ set +vx
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE
++ debugfun ./test.sh
++ set +vx
+ echo xxx 
+ sed s/x/y/ # because this line is here, clearing 3 previous lines from the next "set +vx" would clear it
debugfun $BASH_SOURCE
++ debugfun ./test.sh
++ set +vx
+ sed s/y/x/
xxx
```

I did, finally, come up with this solution but I think it's really ugly and, while close, isn't exactly what I want:

```
SPACES="                        "
PS4='^@\[\e[31m\]+ [\t] \
${SPACES:0:$((${#BASH_SOURCE} > 24 ? 0 : 24 - ${#BASH_SOURCE}))}${BASH_SOURCE:$((${#BASH_SOURCE} < 24 ? 0 : -24))}:\
${SPACES:0:$((3-${#LINENO}))}$LINENO \
${FUNCNAME:-${SPACES:0:20}}${FUNCNAME:+${SPACES:0:$((20 - ${#FUNCNAME}))}} \
$ \[\e[0m\]'
```

The main thing I don't like is that I can't nest the bash string manipulations to not only reverse truncate $BASH_SOURCE, but to get it's basename without a subshell (i.e. combine with echo ${BASH_SOURCE##*/})

I'm out of ideas and would appreciate and clarification or tips on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: I appreciate what you're trying to do, but it would take 1/2 hr to really test and uncover what your problem is, and then work on why the  code is "not quite right". Consider boiling this down to 10 lines of code or less focusing on a simpiler version of your problem. Also, your question near the top about `source ./test2.sh`, 1. does `./test2.sh` start with `#!/bin/bash` ? 2. normally a sourced file is executed in the same process space as the calling shell, so `0 2` seems right to me. You're doing something near the limits of shell programming, don't expect it to be easy ;-) Good luck!

Comment: `DEBUG` isn't a signal. `BASH_SUBSHELL` doesn't actually increment for every subshell, and `PS4` is affected by several factors that aren't particularly useful indicators of anything. The most useful debug output comes from `set -x`, `BASH_COMMAND`, and whatever you stick into a `DEBUG` trap. `set -v` isn't very useful. This has all come up on the mailing list in the past. You'll find some answers if you search there. You might also want to look at the `caller` builtin.

Comment: Thanks, @shellter. I do agree that "0 2" seems right but then where are 2 ++ characters printed by xtrace instead of 1 +? And, no, I didn't have a shebang line in test2.sh.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest forgoing PS4 and doing all trace output in a DEBUG trap. Most, if
not all the information -x prints is available elsewhere. See BASH_SOURCE,
BASH_LINENO, FUNCNAME and BASH_COMMAND.

Like this:

```
function trace()
{
    echo "TRACE" \
         "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}:${FUNCNAME[1]}:" \
         "$BASH_COMMAND"
}

set -o functrace
shopt -s extdebug
trap trace DEBUG
```

Comment: It would help less experienced users (who might come across this problem/answer through Google) if you could post an example or 2 (e.g. a DEBUG trap) - that way your answer has the potential to help a wider range of people =)

Comment: Clarified the answer a little.

Comment: Thanks spbnick. But, as my question mentions, my specific issue with DEBUG signal is that set -v also shows each call to the function ("trace" in your example). I tried disabling both -v and -x and replacing with something like your example but I found that I did need the output of -v (e.g. showing conditional logic, case statements, etc.) and didn't see how to replace it

Comment: Jason, yes, you won't get -v output with a DEBUG trap. However, -v output is
not exactly tracing. As the man page says it does: "Print shell input lines as
they are read." I.e. it doesn't print them when they're executed, but when
they're read. For most of the time shell input is read right before it is
executed, but it isn't so for functions, for example. They will get output
with -v when shell **reads** them, but they don't even have to be executed to
be in the -v output.

I'd suggest taking this into consideration of whether -v is good or bad for
the debugging you need.

Comment: Where do you think we could put that function in a script? at the top? Call it from the start or at the end.?

Comment: @Hanynowsky This function should be defined before the first DEBUG event occurs after the invocation of "trap", which would be the first command after it. Thus the function should be defined anytime before "trap" invocation. The trap invocation should occur right before the point where you would like trace to start.